# Trying to make an anchor within a Paragraph using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make some of my code a link. I am using react class components. I have a paragraph that has the words "Follower's Profile" and referencing a particular URL. Here is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';

class FollowerCard extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="followerContainer">
                {this.props.followers.map(follower =>
                    <div className="followerCard">
                        <img src={follower.avatar_url}/>
                        <p className="followerUserName">Follower's Username: {follower.login}</p>
                        <p className="followerProfile">Follower's Profile: {follower.html_url}</p> 
                    </div>
                    )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default FollowerCard;
```

Basically I am having issues with making {follower.html_url} a clickable url. Currently it will say Follower's Profile: http://somelink.com but "http://somelink.com" isn't clickable. If I try to just wrap this whole thing in an anchor, it also anchors "Follower's Profile" which isn't what I want to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<p className="followerUserName">Follower's Username: <a href={follower.login}>{follower.login}</a></p>
<p className="followerProfile">Follower's Profile: <a href={follower.html_url}>{follower.html_url}</a></p>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It was just that simple... I had tried to put the anchor in the paragraph and did not realize to put the {follower.html_url} after the anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';

class FollowerCard extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="followerContainer">
                {this.props.followers.map(follower =>
                    <div className="followerCard">
                        <img src={follower.avatar_url}/>
                        <p className="followerUserName">Follower's Username: <a href="{follower.login}">{follower.login}</a></p>
                        <p className="followerProfile">Follower's Profile: <a href="{follower.html_url}">{follower.html_url}</a></p> 
                    </div>
                    )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default FollowerCard;
```